# When the heating system plumbing can't be installed inside the wall?

Tags: plumbing

I have recently moved to Sweden (from Brazil). My husband and I have been rebuilding some parts of the house in Sweden. We have hired a company for the work, but I'm surprised with the solution of heating system plumbing they gave to one of the bathrooms. They have installed the heating system plumbing on the wall tiles, like a big frame, but in the original construction (very old) the plumbing weren't aparent. Since I'm not used to heating system in Brazil I 'm not finding the good argument to ask them insert it inside the wall. Can you help me to understand this issue?

[image] Problem are the plumbing heating system like a frame. We want it installed inside the wall, not apparent.

Comment: At this point, it's a little late, no? ;)

Comment: It cannot be a little late, when it is a issue to be solved. The company processed the work when we were travelling. The thing wasn't discussed ou submitted to us. Then, we need to understand what is correct, because if it's necessary the work must be done in the right way.

Comment: This seems like a good lesson in the importance of understanding and approving all the work to be done before allowing construction to begin.

Comment: I think the first step would be to ask the contractor why it was done this way.

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me (though may not suit the tastes of all homeowners), since any heat lost in transit to the heater is lost to the room (rather than inside the wall).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to put it inside the walls (in a house that's already built) is to tear the walls open. When first building the house, this is easy, as the walls are not finished. Unless you were having the tiles redone, or having the opposite side of the wall ripped open, and you coordinated work between the heating contractors and the wall contractors, this is the only way the heating contractors can do the work without ripping huge holes in your walls. Tiles cannot generally be removed and replaced without damage, and once they are a few years old it's very difficult to find matching replacements; what I can see of the wall through the door does not look like boring, easily repaired drywall either, and in any case the heating contractor is probably not in the wall repair business anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear analysis. That was really helpful.